# Could not instantiate bean class [org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream]: Illegal arguments

Tags: java, mongodb, jersey, jax-rs

I have saved an image file to mongodb using InputStream, I am getting this exception at read operation when it is being cast back to Object class.

**Model**

```
 private Object image1;
    public Object getImage1() {
            return image1;
        }

    public void setImage1(InputStream image1) {
            this.image1 = image1;
        }
```

**Exception thrown at this Line**

```
DBObject getDoc = cursorDoc.next();
            User usr = mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(User.class, getDoc);

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.jvnet.mimepull.DataHead$ReadMultiStream]: Illegal arguments for constructor; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:158)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:75)
```

Answer (score 0):

May it make sense to change type of "image1" into InputStream?

Comment: It is throwing same exception